# Error "Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal"

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to make a class as private and got this Error **"Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal"**

I got its meaning but I want to ask why this is not allowed? Are all access modifires not applicable on Class? Why I can't make a class private, protected or protected internal?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Because private means that the member is only visible in the containing class. Since a top-level class has no class containing it it cannot be private (or protected). 
(Internal or public are valid modifiers though).

What would you want private to mean on a top-level class?

Of course all modifiers apply to nested classes, i.e. a class defined within another class.

Comment: What if I want a class to be visible for only classes in a particular namespace ? how to do that, without having to move the class inside another one ?

Comment: Basically you can't. This would be kind of a strange feature to have if you ask me, since the same namespace can exist in multiple assemblies for example.

Comment: Thanks, I guess java has something like package level access or similar, I will look at it..

Comment: I disagree with that explanation. This has nothing to do with containing classes. Ahmed feeling makes perfect sense, at least as a C++ programmer for example, where namespace and class are quasi-synonyms. The real explanation is that C# has chosen that namespaces are far from being equivalent to classes, and accessibility is not configurable at all in namespaces. `public` and `internal` when used in namespaces are merely language support for dll export of symbols. Therefore, the language is disturbing because they recycled keywords. They should have allowed only one qualifier: `exported`.

Comment: I want my class not to be available outside of assembly except for inheritance hence I am using "protected internal". Can anyone explain why I am getting the error in question?

Comment: @David It's not supported by C#.

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fd16xs0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Error list for the same

Answer (score 14):

You can use only `public` or `internal` in the Namespace level

Answer (score 5):

[As Abatonime said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16323202/979621), you can only use `public` or `internal` in the Namespace level.
`private`, `protected`, or `protected internal` can only be used in the Class level.

This works

```
namespace X
{
    class A
    {
        // class code here

        private class B // this class is an inner class
        {
            // class code here
        }
    }
}
```

This won't

```
namespace X
{
    class A
    {
        // class code here
    }

    private class B // this is a class inside a namespace
    {
        // class code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it doesn't make sense. There's no way you can access protected or private classes defined at namespace level, only as nested classes.

Comment: Now that you said that `private` doesn't make sense, try to justify why `public` makes sense, without contradicting yourself. And since we can't write `private`, then what is a class without access qualifier ? No gentlemen, here, definitely, it is C# that doesn't make sense. `private` would mean only visible in this namespace, and `internal private` would mean this namespace in this assembly. It makes perfect sense on the contrary.

Comment: @v.oddou: not sure if it's C# of CLR limitation. anyway, i too would prefer more granular access modifiers (like in Scala perhaps). but current design is solid enough for me and doesn't bother or limit me, unlike many other c# flaws.

Answer (score 2):

Only nested classes could be declared as private.
Not nested classes can be only public or internal (implicit without modifiers)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem because I was creating a custom DLL and only wanted certain classes to be visible to an application using the DLL. So I just remove the modifier completely for classes I wanted to be private (within specific namespaces). The classes remained accessible to other classes within the same namespace in the DLL but did not show up in Intellisense in the calling application. No need for nested classes. The only explanation I can think of is the error message says cannot "explicitly" declare private...it doesn't say anything about implicitly.

```
namespace SmartCardAuthentication
{
  class SmartCardIdentity : IIdentity
  {
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private string _middleInitial;

        ....
   }
}
```

In example code above, class "SmartCardIdentity" is available to other class within same namespace, but not available to calling application when this class is rolled into a DLL. I have not tested it anyother way (i.e. visibility from a class in a different namespace within the DLL.).

Answer (score 0):

The default accessibility of top-level types is `internal`.

The default accessibility of class and struct members is `private`.

The only possible accessibility of interface and enum members is `public`.

So a class is by default `private`, and if you want to access that, you have to put `public` before that.

Comment: The question is talking about access specifiers on *classes* (specifically, top-level classes), not *class members*. This answer doesn't answer the question asked and "a class is by default private" is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Only *Public* and *Internal* are applicable when defining class. If no access modifier is defined before the class default is *internal*.

refer to MSDN - [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fd16xs0(v=vs.90).aspx]

Answer (score 0):

In real world we are focus on visible object
Once object is visible then we talk about scope of the object

**example in real world**

If you walking on street, you see houses in a colony
colony has houses.
If colony is protected no one can't able to see houses
It is consider that no colony no houses is present

**In Programming**

If we make class as private/ protected at top-level
no one known about it

is it present in assembly ?

please correct me, if i am out of the scope